# How can i perform not contains query in sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using sequelize with postgres,
Is there a way to perform a "not contains" statement with sequelize?

something like:

```
[Op.not]: {
    [Op.contains]: ['value1','value2']
}
```

which produces:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE NOT ArrayColumn @>ARRAY['value1','value2']::VARCHAR(255)[]
```

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue had to go to rawish SQL

```
where['<COL_NAME>'][Op.and] = [Sequelize.literal(`'${JS_VARIABLE_ARRAY}' != all (<COL_NAME>)`)];
```

I've built this helper function to construct the my where query

```
const buildWhereQuery = (query, columns) => {
  const parsedObject = {};
  Object.keys(query).forEach((attr) => {
    if (columns.indexOf(attr) !== -1 &&  (query[attr] !== null || query[attr] !== undefined)) {
      parsedObject[attr] = query[attr];
    }
  });
  return parsedObject;
};


const where = buildWhereQuery(query, columnsToQueryAgainst)
```

hope that's help.
using:
node: v10.14.2
sequelize@4.38.0
sequelize-cli@4.0.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Op.not` which will negate the `Op.contains`. Here is the complete code:

```
const query = {
  where: {
    arrayColumn: {
      [Op.not]: {
        [Op.contains]: ["value1", "value2"],
      },
    },
  },
};
```

This will produce

```
SELECT * FROM User WHERE NOT ArrayColumn @> ARRAY['value1','value2']::VARCHAR(255)[]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use as

```
where: {
    $not: { $contains: ['value1','value2'] },
}
```

Comment: This gives me the following error: TypeError: values.map is not a function

Comment: I too get this problem `values.map is not a function` see my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52954784/sequelize-does-not-contain-a-string-within-a-postgresql-array-query