# Sequelize - does not contain a string within a PostgreSQL array query

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have a Sequelize model called `Staff`. On it there's an array field described as follows:

```
const Staff = sequelize.define("staff", {
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    roles: {
        type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING)
    },
});
```

I'm trying to create a GraphQL end point which serves up all staff which don't have 'instructor' in their `roles` field.

I've read [this page of the docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#findall-search-for-multiple-elements-in-the-database), suggesting that I use a combination of `Sequelize.Op`. So I created this:

```
return Staff.findAll({
        where: {
            roles: {
                [Sequelize.Op.not]: {[Sequelize.Op.contains]: ['instructor']},
            }
        }
    }
)
```

The above throws the error:

```
"message": "values.map is not a function"
```

However, if I am to try a query which isn't a combo such as:

```
return models.Staff.findAll({
        where: {
            roles: {
                [Sequelize.Op.contains]: ['instructor']
            }
        }
    }
)
```

The query runs properly, this leads me to believe I perhaps have a syntax error or misunderstanding of how `Op` logic is combined.

Comment: This was reported on GitHub here: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9338 - was closed as an issue because it was stale, would be great to get a fix.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
return models.Staff.findAll({
  where: {
    $not: {
      roles: {
        $contains: ['instructor'],
      },
    },
  },
})
```

The clause `$not` need to be prior than the column you target.

Answer (score 2):

This worked just fine for me:

```
return models.Staff.findAll({
   where: {
    [Sequelize.Op.not]: {
      roles: {
       [Sequelize.Op.contains]: ['instructor'],
      },
    },
  },
})
```

`Sequelize.Op.not` have to come before the column that's being reffered to.